# Cassandra 2.1.8 remote access

Tags: cassandra

I'm configuring Cassandra to accept remote accesses (cqlsh ).
Here's the following that I changed in the cassandra.yaml:

- start_native_transport: true
- start_rpc: true
- rpc_address: my-server-ip

But when I'm launching Cassandra I get the following error:

> "Failed to bind port 9042 on my-server-ip"

If I set start_native_transport: false, I get no error, but I can't get a remote access Cassandra.

Does anyone knows the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Does `$ telnet my-server-ip 9042` (from a remote machine) tell you anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your listen_address in cassandra.yaml. It defaults to localhost, which will not allow for external access. Change it to the private IP, and you will be able to talk to it from the outside. The rpc_address is for Thrift requests.